# Retrieve a value from a cell to use it in a Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to define a dynamic function in Google App-script that is based on referred cell values.

```
function funcname() {
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
    var html = "<script>window.open('LINK URL');google.script.host.close();</script>";
    var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'LINK NAME');

};
```

So in the above code, I would like to refer cell A1 of a specific sheet for 'LINK NAME' and B1 for the actual LINK URL. This function is part of a custom menu, so I would like to see if we can retrieve values based on a cell dynamically as I continue to fill in A and B columns with 'LINK NAME' and 'LINK URLs'

Anything that comes close to this should also help me giving it a shot with some experimentation.

Comment: Does the function need to be ran for each for?

Comment: You can read it with google.script.run using google.script.run on window.,onload or you can load it server side with [templated html]https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).

Comment: @jeanjai77 Can you please explain?

Comment: @Cooper I think this is about calling an HTML right? The suggestion I am looking for is on how to refer to a cell in the script so it can retrieve the value from the cell and make it a part of the script.

Comment: Sheet.getRange("A1").getValue() gets the value in A1

Answer (score 3):

To refer to hard-coded cells:

```js
function funcname() {
  //var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() != "Sheet5") return;
  var cellA1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
  var cellB1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').getValue();
  var html = "<script>window.open('"+cellB1+"');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cellA1);
};
```

---

To get values from columns A and B based on row of active cell (ie retrieve cell values dynamically as you enter in more data):

```js
function funcname() {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() != "Sheet5") return;
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow();
  var cellAx = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  var cellBx = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var html = "<script>window.open('"+cellBx+"');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, cellAx);
};
```

For this script, you would just need to make sure that your active cell is within the row that you want to get the link URL and NAME from.

Comment: Wow, this is super interesting. Thanks much. 

In this, the URL and Name is mentioned in a different sheet-tab say something like "Sheet 5". How do I make sure it checks for these values in only that tab?

Comment: @AdithyaShreshti I have edited my code to include a check to make sure that the active sheet is `Sheet5`, and if not it does not continue.